# Identifying pseudo-duplicates with Perl

Tags: regex, perl, duplicates

I have a list that contains names. There are multiples of the same name. I want to catch the first instance of these pseudo-dupes and anchor them.

Example input

```
Josh Smith
Josh Smith0928340938
Josh Smith and friends

hello
hello1223
hello and goodbye.
```

What I want to do is identify the first occurrence of `Josh Smith` or `hello` and put an anchor such as a pipe `|` in front of it to validate. These are also wildcards as the list is large, so I cannot specifically look for the first match of `Josh Smith` and so on.

My desired output would be this:

```
|Josh Smith
Josh Smith0928340938
Josh Smith and friends

|hello
hello1223
hello and goodbye.
```

I did not provide any code. I am a little in the dark on how to go about this and was hoping maybe someone had been in a similar situation using regex or Perl.

Comment: How do you want to identify the root name? Is it always first, before lines with additions? Otherwise there is no way to choose between searching for `John Smith` or `John Smith and`.

Comment: And why have you removed the clarifying markdown from your question?

Comment: based on your requirements, why wouldn't the and be marked?

Comment: Borodin...I must have removed it when editing accidentally...good question...identifying the root name is kind of my problem...its almost a kind of situation where i want to see if the first word of any given name matches the one above it...and if so put a "|" in front of the first one

Comment: What happens if, after all the `Josh` lines, you get `Josie Lawrence` (is it in the same group because it also starts with `Jos`?) or `Josh Smithson` (It's a different name. Is it in a different group?). And surely there must be instances of two people with the same name? Is there always at least *one* line that doesn't have a suffix?

Answer (score 1):

I think based on what I understand of your requirements you are looking for something like this:

```
$prefix = '';
$buffered = '';
$count = 0;
while ($line = <>) {
    $linePrefix = substr($line,0,length($prefix));
    if ($buffered ne '' && $linePrefix eq $prefix) {
        $buffered .= $line; 
        $count++;
    } else {
        if  ($buffered ne '') {
            print "|" if ($count > 1);  
            print $buffered;
        }
        $buffered = $line;
        $prefix = $line;
        chomp $prefix;
        $count = 1;
    }
}
if ($buffered ne '') {
    if ($count > 1) {
        print "|";
    }
    print $buffered;
}
```

Comment: The occurrences are on *separate lines*. See the edited question.

Comment: undeleted my answer and completely changed it based on what I think are the requirements based on your edits.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, IMO this is a rather interesting question, because you can be creative. As you do not know how to identify the root name, I have to ask if you have to? I have a feeling that you do not need a perfect solution. Therefore, I would go for something simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wn
$N = 4;

if (@prev) {
    $same_start = length $_ >= $N &&
        substr($prev[0], 0, $N) eq substr($_, 0, $N);

    unless ($same_start) {
        print "|", shift @prev if $#prev;
        @prev = grep { print;0 } @prev;
    }
}
push @prev, $_;

}{ print for @prev
```

edit: fixed bug: <print "|", shift @prev;> to <print "|", shift @prev if $#prev;>

Sample output:

```
$ perl josh.pl <josh-input.txt
|Josh Smith
Josh Smith0928340938
Josh Smith and friends

|hello
hello1223
hello and goodbye.
```

Comment: All answers and suggestions much appreciated...i got my task to where i wanted...thanks much